# File sharing via link share or direct access or grant - breaks inheritance

Tags: permissions, security, external-sharing, sharing, sharing-link

I have a doc library with folders and subfolders. When I share a subfolder using either link sharing or direct or grant then the permission inheritance on the subfolder breaks.

Thus now if I add a new user to the parent folder, then that user cannot access the sub folder.

Is this expected? And if so then what is the use case of sharing via link vs direct access vs grant?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this link and see if it applies to your issue? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/broken-permission-inheritance-when-sharing-content/26a402c6-2c27-44af-9ed3-1fb3bb70cbe3

When you share a subfolder (via link or invite), it breaks the permission inheritance from its parent folder. This is because the subfolder now has a unique set of permissions that are different from its parent folder.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, access to the library would be managed using groups rather than giving individuals access to the library directly. This way, when sharing a folder with an individual who does not normally have access to the library, the permissions are modified to include them and will still include the groups which have access to the library. Adding people to these groups will give them access to all items, including those which have been shared with others in this scenario.

If you do need to grant a new group or individual access to all folders and items in a library, you can tick the "Share everything in this folder, even items with unique permissions" option.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying create a group for each parent and subfolder?

Comment: No, you use groups to grant access to the library and folders inherit from that library permissions. As explained in my answer, if you are granting the usual users of the library via the site/AD groups then the sharing functionality is not a problem because it simply adds the additional person to the folder permissions along with your standard library permissions.